# Not getting company info

Tags: linkedin-api

I am new to this linkedin api. I have made a small example which is working when I am using the keyword search by using the following url:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search:(companies:(id,name,universal-name,website-url,industries,status,logo-url,blog-rss-url,twitter-id,employee-count-range,specialties,locations,description,stock-exchange,founded-year,end-year,num-followers))?keywords={IBM}&oauth2_access_token=<access Token>
```

But when I am searching any company info by using the email-domain search then it is giving me 403 error:

```
<error>
  <status>403</status>
  <timestamp>1432820120642</timestamp>
  <request-id>XLWN5Y7T7R</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>Member 385883298 does not have permission to get company 66028</message>
</error>
```

I am using the following url for this:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search:(companies:(id,name,universal-name,website-url,industries,status,logo-url,blog-rss-url,twitter-id,employee-count-range,specialties,locations,description,stock-exchange,founded-year,end-year,num-followers))?email-domain=ibm.com&oauth2_access_token=<acess Token>
```

So as you have posted your answer which is related to this problem I guess you are saying that I have to be the administrator for the company page for which I am searching. As like in my above url i.e. `email-domain=ibm.com`. If I am wrong or not getting the things, please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what is the purpose of the last paragraph of the questions statement. It is making things confusing as I don't see anyone who posted an answer yet.

Comment: Sorry actually some related answers I fond while googling for this issue so by mistake I written this.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the recent changes to the LinkedIn API - you are required to be the administrator of the company you are making API calls on behalf of.  As a result, the company search calls are no longer openly available.

You can make a call to check whether the authenticated user is an Administrator of a given company like this:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{Insert CompanyID here}/relation-to-viewer/is-company-share-enabled?format=json
```

This will return a boolean value.  If true, you're good to go.  If false, you'll need to get an existing company admin to grant the user company administrator status using the tools available on www.linkedin.com

Comment: Is there any other alternative to use company API ?

Comment: @Justin, can you elaborate on what you mean by using the administrators account to make API calls? I'm trying to figure out why the LinkedIn feeds have disappeared all of a sudden. The url being used is `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{0}/updates?oauth2_access_token={1}` but I get the same error on the OP is seeing. Where does the admin come into it?

Comment: LinkedIn must recognize you as an administrator for the company that you are making the API call on behalf of.  Prior to May 12th, this was not a requirement, but it is now.

I've updated the original answer with details on how to determine if the user is an admin that can make the call or not.