# LinkedIn API feeds

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm looking into an issue where a clients LinkedIn feeds on their website have stopped showing. Debugging the problem I've found that I get a 403 error shown below:

> Member xxxxxx does not have permission to get company xxxxx

As the LinkedIn authentication process can be quite difficult to comprehend, I had a look online to see if others have had the same problem, and managed to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510999/not-getting-company-info). It suggests there have been recent changes to the LinkedIn API and users are now required to be the administrator of the company. What exactly does this mean?

From the very beginning we have simply been accessed the feeds by generating a url like this:

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/xxxx/updates?oauth2_access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

This has worked in the past. Do we need to regenerate the Secret and API keys?

### Update

Looking at the announced changes here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

It suggests that the following endpoint will still work (which is exactly what I have):

> /v1/companies/{id}

So I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the access token generated by a account witch is Admin of that company page?
If not hen you will get 403.
The requester needs to be admin of that comapny page in order to get company updates.